# EXEC BAD ACCESS shows no trace/logs even with NSZombiesEnabled set to YES

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm not exactly sure how to debug this but it seems that I'm getting EXEC BAD ACCESS in the main function of my app. There's no trace or logs of what's going on. I have NSZombiesEnabled but it doesn't seem to be showing anything. How would I debug this?

Comment: which Xcode version are you using ? Xcode3 or Xcode4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, pushing multiple view controllers simultaneously will cause this. Hard to debug that!

Answer (score 3):

The first step in debugging is to find out where the crash happens. To do this you need to be able to reproduce the bug.

The Xcode debugger will usually tell you where the crash happened. It doesn't happen in main(), that's simply the entry point for the app and the top of the call stack. You can zoom in to the call stack with the slider at the bottom of the Debugger pane (in Xcode 4).

If the stack trace doesn't include any of your own code, then you may need to set an exception breakpoint in the Breakpoints pane and try again.

If all else fails, you'll have to do some digging:

1) Find a reproducible case where you can make the app crash every time (or almost every time) using the same actions.

2) Since you know what you're doing to make the app crash, you roughly know where in the code you should look. Set breakpoints at strategic places (or use NSLog). After some fishing, you'll find the exact line where the app crashed.

3) Fix the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful.
Mainly you are getting this error because you have released something which is useful in furthur.So try to focus on the release.comment the line where you have used the **release**

Comment: i have a large project (fyi that uses nsoperations). it would take hours to manually comment out all the releases

Comment: but you may know when will happen.like from which controller to which controller going.

Comment: Sachin is right. Else you have to check for Zombies using instruments.

Comment: i don't think it was a release problem. it was a problem with pushing multiple view controllers at the same time which freaked out during transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried too clean and rebuild your project, and restart XCode. Latest versions of Xcode sometimes does EXEC BAD ACCESS int the main function with no reasons…